# How to use cross-entropy in tensorFlow using tf.estimator DNN classifier training

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-serving

I am trying to calculate training loss as cross-entropy in tf.estimator DNN classifier. How can I add cross-entropy loss to the classifier.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`tf.estimator.DNNClassifier`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/estimator/DNNClassifier), which uses a logistic regression head ([link to the sources in 1.3](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.3/tensorflow/python/estimator/canned/dnn.py#L251)).